# Matlab startup error permission denied

Tags: matlab, startup

The error message is as follows. How to deal with this trouble?

Error using connector.internal.autostart.run
Cannot CD to C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp (Directory permission
denied).

[image: Matlab startup error directory permission denied]

Comment: Run MATLAB with sufficient permissions to access the folder.

Comment: ...why would you `cd` to a user's temp dir in your `startup`?! Anyway, it looks like you're trying to `cd` to the "dell" user's application temp data directory, but you are not logged in as the user "dell" (that or the directory's permissions are screwed up)

Comment: What's the output of `getenv('APPDATA')` and/or `getenv('USERNAME')`?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

1 - Go into the MATLAB installation directory using terminal.
2 - Change installation file type in the sense of permission and execution:

> sudo chmod +x install

3 - Run installer:

> sudo ./install

Apparently the aforementioned method provides permission in the necessary steps.